# Very long response time when accessing Apache on OSX

Tags: php, performance, apache, macos, request

Im running Apache on OSX, installed it via ports. For some reason it takes several seconds when im requesting pages from different php scripts. It's not specific to a single script, happens with all of them. I've really spent already a lot of time searching for the cause (also on google), optimized the server, deactivated modules... Still no success.

The macmini is in my local network. Im accessing the pages using a windows machine, the macmini itself and apache are configured to load the php scripts from a network drive. So the data goes over at least three machines. But this should not be any issue, specially since its a gbit network.

Checking the server status with apaches mod_status shows me most of the time a line similar to this for my request:

> 10-0  3612    0/0/0   **W**   0.00    39  0   0.0 0.00    0.00    87.168.224.196  something.org   GET / HTTP/1.1

The W means "Sending Reply" and i can also see here that it takes a lot of time.

Here is the Timing and Size monitored by using Charles Proxy:

```
Timing 
Request Start Time  11.02.11 12:47:31
Request End Time    11.02.11 12:47:31
Response Start Time 11.02.11 12:48:17
Response End Time   11.02.11 12:48:20
Duration    49.33 sec
Request Duration    2 ms
Response Duration   3.13 sec
Latency 46.20 sec
Speed   45,95 KB/s
Response Speed  723,92 KB/s
Size    
Request Header Size 776 bytes
Response Header Size    255 bytes
Request Size    -
Response Size   2,21 MB (2319994 bytes)
Total Size  2,21 MB (2321025 bytes)
Request Compression -
Response Compression    -
```

Any further ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: have you tried with a very simple php script like <?php phpinfo(); ?> ? where was the charles proxy, on the server, on windows? do you have problems only with php or with images or other static files as well?

Comment: Tested it with an image and static html, which comes through fast. Charles is running on windows from where I request the page. As mentioned in another comment it becomes a lot faster when I copy the script(s) to the macmini but this is not really a solution I would like to use because I would loose backup functionality I have by using my NAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to read what you pasted, but how long is it actually taking?
I don't think the gbit network offers any benefit over a mbit network in this case, since it is basically about response times in stead of bandwidth.

How long does it take from the machine it is running on?

Comment: I've updated my question.
Response Start Time 11.02.11 12:48:17
Response End Time   11.02.11 12:48:20
Duration    49.33 sec
Request Duration    2 ms
Response Duration   3.13 sec
Latency 46.20 sec
Speed   45,95 KB/s

Comment: To pin down the problem you could try to move the PHP scripts to a local drive on the apache machine. See if it makes any difference.

Comment: This increased the speed indeed a lot. But I don't want to move all projects from the NAT to the macmini, there several reasons for that. So I guess my problem might be Samba?

Comment: Are there a lot of includes in your script? I think that could be explanation for the latency problem. Image it takes 2 seconds to load a script for the NAS to your macmini, every include will put an additional 2 seconds to your latency! Perhaps it would be better if your NAS could run Apache or to make your macmini into your NAS :)

Comment: It's loading the framework + the application over the network. Arf... I think you're right I need to change something in my network. :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Apache is configured to do some reverse DNS which means that with each request it tries to do a DNS lookup with your internal IP (and possibly waits until the request times out because there is no DNS server that can match your internal IP).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. I don't think it's the reverse DNS. Any way to debug/confirm this? mod_status also does not show "d" which would be the DNS lookup.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/dns-caveats.html I've also checked this again. My configuration is right and matches the documentation here.